# Problemas al leer una base de datos sqlite

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Hola tengo el siguiente código que llama a la base de datos de mi aplicación. Lo único que necesito es contar la cantidad de datos. SOY USUARIA ROOT

```
    public int contar() throws SQLException{

    Cursor mcursor = null;
    mcursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query("Contacts",new String[]{"_id"}, null ,null,null,null,null );


    return mcursor.getCount();

}
```

pero al consultar la base me sale este error... Que nunca me ocurrio y es la primera vez. Ojo ya le di los permisos respectivos a la base

> 05-11 00:48:59.313 25496-25496/conts.com.contactos D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0

```
05-11 00:48:59.493 25496-25496/conts.com.contactos D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

05-11 00:48:59.523 25496-25496/conts.com.contactos D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2

05-11 00:48:59.533 25496-25496/conts.com.contactos D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{96c1df6 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #10203a4 android:id/toast_layout_root}

05-11 00:48:59.553 25496-26587/conts.com.contactos W/FileUtils: Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.miapp/databases/MIBASE.db): android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

05-11 00:48:59.553 25496-26587/conts.com.contactos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Process: conts.com.contactos, PID: 25496

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 28 to 1

    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:360)

    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:254)

    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)

    at contwhats.com.contactoswhatsapp.DeveloperBD.contar(DeveloperBD.java:61)

    at contwhats.com.contactoswhatsapp.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:55)

    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

    05-11 00:48:59.563 25496-25708/conts.com.contactos D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [328x104]-format:1

    05-11 00:48:59.643 25496-25496/conts.com.contactos D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1

    05-11 00:49:00.093 25496-25708/conts.com.contactos D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xf3734280 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xe2193820

    05-11 00:49:00.443 25496-25496/conts.com.contactos D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null

    05-11 00:49:03.043 25496-25496/conts.com.contactos D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
```

Si me pueden dar un pedazo de codigo para salvar este error no se cual es el problema. Un saludo Lina

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esta otra pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053786/cant-downgrade-database-from-version-2-to-1-even-after-fresh-install-and-re-run

Comment: He agregado una respuesta, agrega tu clase que extiende de SQLiteOpenHelper , si estas en desarrollo simplemente elimina la aplicación y al crearse nuevamente la base de datos esta tendrá la versión 1. @FanteEsaprender.

Answer (score -1):

El mensaje no tiene que ver con permisos, se debe a que creaste una base de datos con una versión superior a la que tratas de actualizar en el constructor de `SQLitOpenHelper`.

Actualmente tu código trata de actualizar a una nueva versión, pero esta es menor que la que tiene tu aplicación, tienes estas opciones:

> - Si es una prueba o una versión de desarrollo, simplemente elimina el caché o elimina la aplicación y vuelve a subir la aplicación a tu dispositivo.
> - Si es una aplicación de producción asigna la versión 29, ya que esta detectando tienes creada una base de datos con versión 28.

Para cambiar a una nueva versión este es un ejemplo:

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 29;

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
     ...
     ...
```

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.